# how to read git show command output

Tags: git, git-show

I am just getting into VC and in particular git. I am aware of basic commands like `git add/commit/remote` but having a hard time understanding the output:

```
$ git show f27d852

commit f27d852fc750a9c3f71eaf0acf586164b76faddf
Author: myusername <myemail@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 28 22:59:35 2016 +0530

    changed color to a different color

diff --git a/css/business-casual.css b/css/business-casual.css
index bbd44d7..ee1765e 100644
--- a/css/business-casual.css
+++ b/css/business-casual.css
@@ -194,5 +194,5 @@ footer p {
 /* CUSTOM CSS - BY ME */

 .brand {
-       color: #ff0000;
-       }
\ No newline at end of file
+       color: #ffdd000;
+       }
```

What does each line mean? How to read it. can anyone explain?

Thanks
dk

Comment: This is just showing you the details of the most recent commit (on the current branch) - metadata plus the diff.  Which part in particular is problematic?

Comment: I do not understand the following lines: `diff --git a/..... b/` `--- a/...
+++ b/..`  `@@ -194,5 +194,5 @@ footer p {` (why there is a reference of `footer p{}`, which was never changed and moreover no where near line 194) and the line `\ No newline at end of file` when infact there were blank lines at eof.

Comment: The `No newline at end of file` message indicates that one of the files (the first one, in this case) is incomplete. The last line is not terminated by a newline character, as lines in a text file are supposed to be. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline). The diff output tells you everything about the changes between the two files, even this minor detail that you might not care about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
commit f27d852fc750a9c3f71eaf0acf586164b76faddf
```

The sha1 of the commit.

```
Author: myusername <myemail@gmail.com>
```

The author's name and email, which might be different from the committer's name and email.

```
Date:   Tue Jun 28 22:59:35 2016 +0530
```

The author date, which might be different from the committer date.

```
changed color to a different color
```

The commit log message. It could be one line, or the first part + empty line(s) + the other part. The only line or the first part before the empty line(s) is `subject`, and the other part after the empty line(s) is `body`.

```
diff --git a/css/business-casual.css b/css/business-casual.css
```

The two files that have been compared.

```
index bbd44d7..ee1765e 100644
```

`bbd44d7` is the sha1 of the blob before the change and `ee1765e` the sha1 of the blob after the change. You could run `git show <blob-sha1>` or `git cat-file -p <blob-sha1>` to see the blob's content.

```
--- a/css/business-casual.css
```

The file before the change.

```
+++ b/css/business-casual.css
```

The file after the change.

```
    @@ -194,5 +194,5 @@ footer p {
 /* CUSTOM CSS - BY ME */

 .brand {
-       color: #ff0000;
-       }
\ No newline at end of file
+       color: #ffdd000;
+       }
```

`194` is the diff start line and `5` is the context lines. `footer p {` indicates where the diff part locates. The lines without prefixing + or - are unchanged lines. If you add one line, it's a +. If you delete a line, it's a -. If you modify a line, it's a - and a +.

Comment: Although, I understood most of it from another answer on SO however still thanks for taking the pain to reply to this in a much more detailed manner than the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

It provides the details about commit and then list of changed files with its differencies (see [unified diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html) for details):

```
# commit id:
commit f27d852fc750a9c3f71eaf0acf586164b76faddf
# author:
Author: myusername <myemail@gmail.com>
# date committed:
Date:   Tue Jun 28 22:59:35 2016 +0530
# commit message:
    changed color to a different color
# difference for css/business-casual.css :
diff --git a/css/business-casual.css b/css/business-casual.css
```